# Is Microformat's date-value-pattern fully accessible?

Tags: accessibility, microformats, abbr

Has there been an announcement (outside [microformats.org](http://microformats.org)) that the [value-class-pattern](http://microformats.org/wiki/value-class-pattern) is fully accessible?

e.g. given `<abbr class="value" title="2008-06-24">this Tuesday</abbr>`, will a screen reader say "24 June 2008" or will it say "2008 dash 6 dash 24"?

#### History

Microformats came along, and were great, except that dates etc were stored in abbr tags:

```
<abbr class="dtstart" title="20070312T1700-06">
  March 12, 2007 at 5 PM, Central Standard Time
</abbr>`
```

This lead to screen readers doing ridiculous things as noted in [hAccessibility](http://www.webstandards.org/2007/04/27/haccessibility/).  Now that  [microformats.org](http://microformats.org) have [released](http://microformats.org/2009/05/12/value-class-pattern) the [value-class-pattern](http://microformats.org/wiki/value-class-pattern) it's a lot better.

But I'm left unable to find a declaration from WaSP (or another accessibility source not directly tied to microformats) that declaratively states that they are now accessible to screen readers etc.

Comment: I don't remember seeing a definitive solution to the problem. All solutions have had issues with either accessibility or one of the microformat principals. You may want to ask on the micrioformat mailing list.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing saying that screen readers can't be smart and guess what is a date, [but in practice they aren't smart at all](http://www.paciellogroup.com/blog/?p=41)…

To solve that problem once for all HTML5 defines `<time>` element. However, it's probably not supported by any screen readers nor microformat parsers yet. You can easily test against [Google's implementation](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets).